# Why Oracle doesn't see the alias in the sub sub query?

Tags: sql, oracle

It looks like Oracle doesn't see the c alias in the subquery. The returned error is: ORA-00904: "C"."FLH_PUNTO_EROGAZIONE": identificativo non valido

It seems oracle just looks for alias in the 1 degree external statement

```
SELECT (SELECT 1
          FROM (SELECT 1 AS SomeAlias
                  FROM out.ANAG_PDF_PWR_T840
                 WHERE campo34 = c.flh_punto_erogazione
                UNION
                SELECT 1
                  FROM out.ANAG_PDF_T812
                 WHERE campo34 = c.flh_punto_erogazione) Something)
  FROM etl_elab_interf_flat f, eni_flussi_hub c,  eni_info_extra_forn ief, conf_forniture forn
 WHERE     f.eif_campo198(+) = c.flh_id_messaggio
       AND f.idde_identif_dati_ext_id(+) = c.idde_identif_dati_ext_id
AND c.flh_punto_erogazione IN ('8003576015', '8003576054', '8003576551', '8003576565')
       AND eif_campo200 IN ('FORNITURA_ENI')
       AND c.flh_flag_ann = 'N'
       --
       AND forn.forn_old_codice_fornitura (+) = c.flh_fornitura
       AND forn.forn_fornitura_id  = ief.forn_fornitura_id(+);
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? Unexpected results? Please clarify your issues and your exact question.

Comment: This formulation works:
(SELECT DECODE (COUNT (1), 0, 'NO', 'SI')
        FROM (  SELECT campo34 AS campo34 FROM out.ANAG_PDF_PWR_T840 
                UNION 
                SELECT campo34 FROM out.ANAG_PDF_T812 
                ) Something
                WHERE campo34 = c.flh_punto_erogazione                 
                )
               "Flusso creaz. Pdf presente OUT",

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any issues with `c.flh_punto_erogazione` and or the query, because it works like-

```
SQL> select (select 1 
               from dual b 
              where c.dummy||'YZ'=b.dummy||'YZ') col
       from dual c
      where c.dummy||'YZ'='XYZ';

COL
----------
1
```

Unless, the column `flh_punto_erogazione` does not exist in the table `eni_flussi_hub`, or you may have misspelled it.

Comment: I understood!!!! It's the FROM clause. I remembered that it cannot use  alias from external statement.